# Multilevel multinomial logistic regression in matlab

Tags: matlab, regression, logistic-regression, multinomial

I have been searching for the code in matlab for multilevel multinomial logistic regression for many days. I am new to the matlab, can anyone help me in finding the code for that in matlab?

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself? If yes can you show us what you tried and what exactly didn't work yet?

Comment: oops I did not, but is there any package or build-in function in matlab?